# How do I politely tell someone to leave a room?

Tags: conversation

For example, I'm talking to A and B in a meeting room, and then I want to talk with B and don't want A to listen. How do I politely ask A to leave the room?

Comment: This seems like it would fit the workplace SE instead? (A, would you mind giving us the room?)

Comment: I agree with Smock, also this is a matter of opinion. "Would you mind if I had a private word with B?"

Comment: @Smock - If a fluent speaker requested a polite way to ask for a private word with someone that would not offend coworkers, then I would lean toward your suggestion. However, if an English learner is completely unaware of phrasal verbs and idioms such as "give us the room" and "private word", I think ELL is perhaps a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm tempted to say *please leave*, but, really, this question is far too broad. I'm sure I could come up with about twenty different ways of asking this in a matter of minutes. (And, even with that, what I consider to be polite, others might not. Or vice versa.)

Comment: @Smock Whether it fits another platform is not the concern here. The thing is, my question fits this platform.

Comment: @JasonBassford If you have 20 different expressions for this situation, why not show them in your answer?

Comment: @XYZ First of all, I was only commenting. Second, that would serve little purpose. If any number of phrases could be used, then it wouldn't be a good answer. This site is predicated on having (ideally) a single answer to a question. (Although a few examples can be given *as* examples—rather than actual answers.) But if everybody has a different opinion as to what a polite phrase would be in this case, then it's not objectively useful. (I've already voted to close this as opinion-based, so I'm not going to provide my own subjective answer.)

Comment: @jason " This site is predicated on having (ideally) a single answer to a question. " I must strongly disagree. Often there are several equally good ways to do or say something. This was and is very true on the original StackOverflow site, where there are in many cases three or four equally good solutions to a particular problem, adn it is certainly true in English usage.Indeed there is almost never just a single correct answer.  It is closer to true on the se.law site, but even there, there are often two good answers at least.

Comment: @DavidSiegel If we weren't looking for (ideally) a single answer that is objectively correct, we would have not have the close vote reasons *primarily opinion-based* or *too broad*. Together, those indicate that we do *not* want questions that can result in multiple or subjective answers. Many questions *do* result in more than one answer—but they shouldn't be *designed* to do so. That's why any *list 100 synonyms for X* type questions are immediately closed. This is such a question. It's effectively asking, *How many different ways can I politely ask somebody to leave a room?*

Comment: @Jason, I must still strongly disagree. A purely onion-based question is closed because there are no objective criteria by which to vote any answer up or down.  Questions such as 'which is the best programing language" are opnion-based. Questions such as "How do I pass a value to a function" or "how is a participle used" have multiple, objectively correct, sourcable answers, usually a small closed set of answers. **Those** are the ideal answers here, not the rare unique answers.

Comment: @DavidSiegel What you just said applies to what is polite. Different people have different opinions about what's polite. Some will say something is; others will say that it isn't. Most of the time I see questions like this, there is inevitably debate (just like the kind we're having). And even if you don't think that it's debatable if something is polite or not (which I would find odd), I don't see how you could argue that there aren't a very *large* number of ways of phrasing the request asked for in this question—polite or not.

Comment: @jason, I didn't argue that **this** question is not opinion based, although I think it is not without criteria, and so not PUREly opnion-based. My argument is with your general statement that the ideal is only one answer. I think the ideal is about 3-5 answers

Answer (score 1):

To **A** you might say the following:

> Would you mind excusing us for a moment?

Comment: How do I understand 'excusing us'? Does it mean that I need to talk to B or does it possibly mean something else?

Comment: @XYZ That would be taken to mean, "please leave us alone" or less likely, but depending on tone and body language, please let us go elsewhere and leave you alone.

Comment: @David thanks for explaining that to XYZ! Just to confirm, this is also how I interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

- "I need to have a word with B.  Could you give us a moment?"
- "Would you mind stepping outside?  I need to speak to B."